# Ecto Repo.get_by with multple 'or' clauses

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am attempting use Ecto Repo.get_by with multiple clauses, and I'm having trouble finding syntax examples. I need to query where either or 2 fields in the DB match, so an 'or' condition between the clauses. I can't figure out if this is even possible.

```
Repo.get_by(User, [username: username, email: username], prefix: :accounts)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Repo.get_by` doesn't allow `OR`ing the clauses. You'll need to write a full query using `from`, or a combination of `where` and `or_where`, and then pipe to `Repo.one`:

```
from(u in User, where: u.username == ^username or u.email == ^username)
|> Repo.one
```

```
User
|> where(username: ^username)
|> or_where(email: ^username)
|> Repo.one
```

To add the prefix to this query, you can do [this](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-query-prefix).